# Scala pattern matching option None with or without binding

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I would like to do the following pattern matching :

```
minReachableInt match {
   case None | Some(n) if n <= 0 =>
     println("All positive numbers can be reached")
   case _ =>
     println("Not all positive numbers can be reached")
}
```

Of course, it does not compile, because n is not matched in `None`. But as I don't need it in the subsequent code, how can I achieve my result without duplicating the code, in the most beautiful way you could imagine ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are limits to what you can do with pattern matching syntax, so don't try to use it to express all your logic.

This problem could be expressed using `filter`:

```
minReachableInt filter (_ <= 0) match {
  case None =>
    println("All positive numbers can be reached")
  case _ =>
    println("Not all positive numbers can be reached")
}
```